# When do we say a connection is established in a Web Application?

Tags: html, web

Assume I have a simple ASP.NET MVC application with an Index view that just shows some static data.

Considering the fact that the web is stateless, when a browser requests for this index.cshtml, a HTTP Get request is made and the server sends the contents of the page to the client.

In Such case is there an entity called connection? If so when can we say that connection is established?

Hope my question is clear.

Comment: the connection is established at tcp level, then the http conversation goes through

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A connection is established between the client (browser) and the underlying web server (IIS) prior to any invocation of your MVC application.

If you get a request in your web application, then a TCP connection has already been established and an HTTP request has been sent to the server over TCP. With keep-alive semantics, multiple requests may use the same connection, and of course multiple actions could even be called for the same request.

So basically, the establishment of a connection is not something that is particularly useful for a web application to indicate or track, if that is what you are trying to do.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more accurate to say that the connection is established _by the browser_, **to** the underlying web server?

Comment: Well yes and no. It is initiated by the client, but both the client and server participate in the establishment of a TCP connection through the SYN/SYN-ACK/ACK handshake. I don't think being that technical is really necessary for this question, though. The point is that it's handled at a level that is basically invisible to a web application.

Comment: I went ahead and updated my answer to be a bit more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

The connection is estabished to the IIS Server/Process and then forwarded to .NET, so the moment IIS receives it, it's 'established'

Comment: So in such a case when can we say that the connection is now closed?

Comment: I would expect (Don't quote me here...) that the connection is closed (providing everything goes well) when all data has been flushed by the server and received by the client.

Can I ask such interest? I would ask much of this be "out of scope" to a developer?

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP protocol is based on the TCP protocol. Before the GET request is made, a TCP connection must be made.

"The connection is closed" happens when the TCP connection is closed, usually after a single request/response interaction.

The connection may be kept open by using Keep-Alive.